# What happens when Shiva dance?

Tags: shiva

What happens when Shiva dance? Shiva the mightiest of mighty and also merciful by whose eye brows all gods work. What happens when this auspicious dance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dedicated to Shiva From [Mahimna strotra](http://www.ms.uky.edu/%7Esohum/sanskrit/mahimna/mahimna.htm).

> मही पादाघाताद्‌ व्रजति सहसा संशयपदं
>
> पदं विष्णोर्भ्राम्यद्‌ भुज-परिघ-रुग्ण-ग्रह- गणम्‌।
>
> मुहुर्द्यौर्दौस्थ्यं यात्यनिभृत-जटा-ताडित-तटा
>
> जगद्रक्षायै त्वं नटसि ननु वामैव विभुता॥ १६॥
>
> You dance for protecting the world, but strangely, your glorious act appears to produce the opposite result in that the earth suddenly struck by your dancing feet doubts that it is coming to an end; even VishhNu's domain is shaken in fear when your mace like arms bruise the planets; the godly region feels miserable when its banks are struck by your agitated matted locks (of hair)!

Comment: During daily (tandava) dance of Shiva nothing happens. He dances during Sunrise, noon and sunset and no destruction is happening to this world. You should mention  dance as "ferocious Tandava" which he does only at end times. Even when Shiva gets angry, Parvathi Devi will pacify him by her Lasya Dance.